# Scraping websites with PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument

I'm trying to scrap information directly from the maersk website.
Exemple, i'm trying scraping the information from this URL https://www.maersk.com/tracking/221242675
I Have a lot of tracking nunbers to update every day on database, so I dicided automate a little bit.

But, if have the following code, but its saying that need JS to work. I alredy even tryed with curl, etc.
But nothing work. Any one know another way?

I tryed the following code:

```
<?php
// ------------ teste 14 ------------
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.maersk.com/tracking/#tracking/221242675'); //get the html returned from the following url
echo $html;
$ETAupdate = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $ETAupdate->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html
    
    $ETA_xpath = new DOMXPath($ETAupdate);

    //get all the h2's with an id
    $ETA_row = $ETA_xpath->query('//strong');

    if($ETA_row->length > 0){
        foreach($ETA_row as $row){
            echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked their [APIs](https://www.maersk.com/digital-solutions/data-integrations/api)?

Comment: Hi, yes i checked, unfortunately the maersk have API to many things, but none works for tracking. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scrape the data directly from their API requests, rather than trying to scrape the page URL directly (Unless you're using something like puppeteer, but I *really* don't recommend that for this simple task)

I took a look at the site and the API endpoint is:

https://api.maersk.com/track/221242675?operator=MAEU

This will return a JSON-formatted response which you can parse and use to extract the details. It'll also give you a much easier method to access the data rather than parsing the HTML. Example below.

```json
{
    "tpdoc_num": "221242675",
    "isContainerSearch": false,
    "origin": {
        "terminal": "YanTian Intl. Container Terminal",
        "geo_site": "1PVA2R05ZGGHQ",
        "city": "Yantian",
        "state": "Guangdong",
        "country": "China",
        "country_code": "CN",
        "geoid_city": "0L3DBFFJ3KZ9A",
        "site_type": "TERMINAL"
    },
    "destination": {
        "terminal": "DCT Gdansk sa",
        "geo_site": "02RB4MMG6P32M",
        "city": "Gdansk",
        "state": "",
        "country": "Poland",
        "country_code": "PL",
        "geoid_city": "3RIGHAIZMGKN3",
        "site_type": "TERMINAL"
    },
    "containers": [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: WOOOOWWW! Man Thank you soooo much. I don't even know this exist! :D

Comment: You can see this in the "Network" developer tools on Chrome, this is how many websites typically load data into their frontend nowadays. Please mark this as the correct answer if this helped! :)

Comment: Conor i feeling a little bit newbie!